# ¿Cómo coloco una marca de agua en un PDF con iTextSharp en Visual basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itextsharp

qué tal, tengo el siguiente código en un botón, con esto genero un archivo PDF en el cual aparece el contenido de los textbox del formulario, todo bien, pero necesito ponerle una marca de agua la cual sea una imagen (se supone que es un certificado y se genera el pdf con los resultados impresos ahí...). ¿Serían tan amables de ayudarme y aconsejarme? En serio lo necesito mucho, he estado aprendiendo esto solo, soy principiante y mi programa está casi listo. Les dejo el código explicado:

```
Private Sub btnGenerarPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerarPDF.Click
    Dim SaveFileDialog As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim ruta As String
    'Muestro el Save File Dialog u guardo el contenido en pdf

    With SaveFileDialog
        .Title = "guardar"
        'Selecciono la ruta de generación por defecto
        .InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        .Filter = "Archivos pdf (.pdf)|.pdf"
        .FileName = txtNombre.Text + " Emisiones contaminantes"
        .OverwritePrompt = True
        .CheckPathExists = True
    End With
    If SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ruta = SaveFileDialog.FileName
    Else
        ruta = String.Empty
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Vamos a generar el PDF
    Try
        'Crear documento
        Dim document As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4)
        'Configuración hoja
        document.PageSize.Rotate()
        document.AddAuthor("PRT MANAGER")
        document.AddTitle("Certificado de emisiones contaminantes")
        'Con esto haremos que el documento sea presentado como una página simple
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New System.IO.FileStream(ruta, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        writer.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage
        'Abrimos el documento para comenzar a escribir
        document.Open()
        'Definimos el tipo de documento
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        'Definimos fuente y tamaño
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12)
        cb.BeginText()

        cb.SetTextMatrix(35, 787)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtConsecionario.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(35, 775)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtDirPlanta.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(180, 775)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtTelefono.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(35, 763)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtCiuPlanta.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(35, 751)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtIDPlanta.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(200, 751)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtPatente.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 751)
        cb.ShowText(Me.txtDV.Text)

        cb.SetTextMatrix(400, 751)
        cb.ShowText(Me.cboDia.Text)
     'etc....

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error en la creacion de la nota", "PRTManager", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Mira el código de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15612044/579895) y su primera respuesta.